# how to add a div(customized footer) in inappbrowser of ionic 1 application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

how to inject a html page with specific height and width under bottom:0 in inappbrowser.

Reason : I need to open my link at the bottom of the inappbrowser with width:100% and height:70px;

Could you please help me to resolve this

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKWsj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate .html file which have its own specified css and then you need to inject it in index.html like this.

```
<div class="" ng-include src="'yourFile.html'"></div>
```